# C# to VB.net Byte Conversions

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, byte

I'm trying to use some code from the Opus project in VB.net, it was originally written for C, but I am integrating it into another application...

```
    byte[] _notEncodedBuffer = new byte[0];

    byte[] soundBuffer = new byte[e.BytesRecorded + _notEncodedBuffer.Length];
```

I'm not sure how these should be translated into VB.net, I have translated all the code but this and am getting good results, just not entirely sure on these, had all kinds of errors with my attempts, including Identifier expected, Bracket identifier missing etc! :(

```
    Dim wavNEB As Byte() = New Byte [0]

    Dim wavSnd As Byte() = New Byte [e.BytesRecorded + wavNEB.Length]
```

That was my last attempt, but no cigar!

Any help much appreciated, I rarely have to break VB or C out so it's not a strong point...

Comment: Change brackets `[]` to parhentesis `()`...

Comment: And subtract 1 from the number inside the parentheses. VB expects the index of the last item rather than the number of items in the array. E.g. `Dim wavNEB(-1) as Byte`

Comment: This is most definitely not C. It looks like C# to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VB.NET, the syntax

```
Dim ArrayName(N) As ArrayType
```

is equivalent to the C# code:

```
ArrayType[] ArrayName = new ArrayType[N+1];
```

Additionally, if `ArrayName` has been declared as `ArrayType`, the executable statement

```
ReDim ArrayName(N)
```

would be equivalent to the C# code

```
ArrayName = new ArrayType[N+1];
```

Additionally, VB.NET offers the syntax

```
ReDim Preserve ArrayName(N)
```

as a means of replacing `ArrayName` with a reference to a new array of size N+1 whose contents are pre-loaded with those of the old array.